# Recorrer base de datos para sacarme el total

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas estoy sacando un mensaje por si el cliente tiene una factura pendiente pero a la hora hacer la suma de los totales no consigo hacer que me las agrupe. Porque si en un pedido van dos productos se crean dos lineas en la BD entonces al sumar me suma dos veces lo mismo.

```
$us = $res['IdUsuario'];

$pedidos = $mysqli->query("SELECT Total, FORMAT(SUM(Total), 2) as suma, estadoFact, Iduser, id, pedidoid FROM pedidos WHERE estadoFact = 0 AND Iduser = $us");
   $ped = $pedidos->fetch_array();
   $esta = $ped['estadoFact'];
   $aban = $ped['abandonado'];

   for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($ped['estadoFact']); $i++) {
     if($aban[$i] == 0){
      echo "<div class=\"col-12 cuadroImpago\">
               <h2>Tienes Facturas pendientes</h2>
               <p>Dirijete a Facturación y abonalas para impedir cortes de servicio</p>
               <h3>" .$ped['suma']."</h3>
             </div>";
           }
        }
```

La idea del for es para que lo recorriera, pero algo no estaré haciendo bien.

Comment: Debes agregar un  `GROUP BY` para que funcione... Aunque, no entiendo por qué repites la columna `Total` ni las otras columnas del `SELECT`...  Quizá sea esto lo que necesites: `SELECT FORMAT(SUM(Total), 2) as suma FROM pedidos WHERE estadoFact = 0 AND Iduser = $us GROUP BY Iduser` ... He quitado algunas columnas porque no sé si las necesitas o si cumplen las restricciones de agregación. MySQL es más permisivo con eso, pero si necesitas esas otras columnas debes asegurar que no hay posibilidad de repeticiones al agrupar.

Comment: No estoy seguro pero dado el enunciado entiendo que sólo tienes una única tabla. Para este tipo de casos lo normal es tener 2 tablas relacionadas, por ejemplo `pedidos` y `detalles_pedidos`; `facturas` y `detalles_factura`; `ventas` y ~detalles_ventas`. En cualquier caso sería de agradecer que nos facilites la estructura de tu/s tabla/s y algunos datos de ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios. Con el GROUP BY Iduser tampoco funciona. Piensa que hay una tabla que guarda los pedidos, al llevar algunos mas de un producto se generan más filas, de ahi la necesidad de agruparlos. Las otras columnas las saco por que si ves utilizo esas variables. La cuestión es que tengo que hacer entender que si hay dos producto con la misma pedidoid no sume esos dos o mas

Comment: No se entiende el problema. Por favor, muestra tus tablas y un ejemplo de lo que sale, lo que queres que salga, y sobre que datos estas trabajando. ese query que estas usando es muy raro y no deja comprender a que tratas de referir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta consulta te podría valer:

```
SELECT p.Total, FORMAT(SUM(p.Total), 2) as suma, p.estadoFact, p.Iduser, p.id, p.pedidoid 
  FROM (SELECT Total, estadoFact, Iduser, id, pedidoid  
          FROM pedidos
         WHERE estadoFact = 0 
           AND Iduser = $us
         GROUP BY pedidoid 
        ) as p
```

Básicamente se trata de agrupar primero por el campo/s que necesitas y después realizar el `SELECT` sobre esos datos ya agrupados, por lo cual se descartarán duplicados.

Dependiendo el caso te podría valer también un `DISTINCT' (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/distinct-optimization.html)

Tienes más información en la sección [SUBCONSULTAS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html) de la documentación oficial de mysql.

Comment: no entiendo esta consulta.. si se puede resolver con una sola haciendo directamente el sum como subconsulta, para que hacer todo este baruyo? ademas hacer un group by, sobre cosas que no se sumarizan tampoco es una buena idea (aunque mysql lo permita, no es sql estandar)

Comment: No quiere sumar todos los del `group by` quiere sumar solo **uno** por cada `pedidoid`, Yo Tampoco tengo claro que pretende, no sabemos que estructura usa ni porque... solo represente en SQL lo que el estaba pidiendo. O eso creo.

Comment: Si no se entiende lo que pide, lo mejor es esperar a que clarifique su pregunta. por eso le pedi datos, porque creo que algo no anda bien en ese programa.

Comment: No dije que no entendiera lo que pide, dije que no entiendo lo que pretende. Muchisimas veces no coincido en criterio con el OP, pero aun asi respondo con lo que creo que quiere hacer. A veces incluyo como lo haría yo, pero no siempre.

Comment: Gracias por vuestro aporte chicos! el código que me ofrece @Fly es el correcto para sacar lo que estaba buscando. Siento si no me he explicado bien. Voy a intentar hacer un resumen. Tengo una tabla de pedidos, en ella se guardan los pedidos por filas, si un pedido lleva más de un producto se generan distintas filas en la BD pero con el mismo `pedidoid`, de ahi queria sacar el total pero que tuviese en cuenta de agruparlos por `pedidoid`ya que si nosalen datos duplicados. El resto de campos que veis son necesarios para sacar otros datos. Gracias a todos

Comment: Es decir, tienes lineas en varios ¿¡"documentos"!?, con mismo pedidoid y mismo articulo, pero que realmente se refieren a la misma "entrega", por lo tanto necesitas descartar duplicados  ¿es optima esa forma de gestionar la información? ¿no es algo ambiguo?